# Excel removing all rows where the first, last, and email are all the same

Tags: excel, filter, transactions

I'm struggling over how to remove certain rows in my excel sheet. Right now I have something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Pxi.png

```
First   Last    Email               Amount
A       B       AB@gmail.com        $25 
A       B       AB@gmail.com        $25 
A       B       AB@gmail.com        $25 
A       B       AB@gmail.com        $25 
Z       Y       AB@gmail.com        $10 
1       2       12@gmail.com        $50.00 
1       2       12@gmail.com        $50.00 
3       4       12@gmail.com        $50.00 
Qwerty  Uiop    Qwerty@gmail.com    50
Qwerty  Uiop    Qwerty@gmail.com    50
Qwerty  Uiop    Qwerty@gmail.com    50
Qwerty  Uiop    Qwerty@gmail.com    50
```

I want to know how i can analyze this data and delete all people who have only entered the same first and last name and email for all of their transactions. For example, in this image, Qwerty@gmail.com has 4 transactions, but they all have the same first and last name, so i want to delete all rows containing qwerty@gmail.com. However, AB@gmail.com has 4 transactions with the name A B and 1 transaction with the name Z Y, so i don't want to remove any rows containing AB@gmail.com.

Can anyone help suggest a way this could be done?

Comment: Do you not want to remove the duplicates of the A B AB@gmail.com lines so you juts have one copy of these and also keep the Z Y AB@gmail.com line?

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a built-in facility for removing Duplicate values.

1. Select the range of cells containing the data
2. On the Data tab click Remove Duplicates
3. Under Columns, select the columns you wish to include in the check for duplicates
4. Click OK
5. After the message saying how many records will be removed, Click OK

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Advanced Filter` with a formula criteria.

The formula:

```
A2: =COUNTIFS(Sheet3!$C$8:$C$19,C8,Sheet3!$A$8:$A$19,A8,Sheet3!$B$8:$B$19,B8)/COUNTIF(Sheet3!$C$8:$C$19,C8)<>1
```

### Before

[image]

## Filter Dialog

[image]

## After

[image]